# In-place rotation of 1-dimensional representation of n x n square matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix, rotation, transform, linear-algebra

I have a `n x n` matrix represented as a 1-D array. The top-left corner starts with index 0. Index i is computed as `i = x * n + y` where x and y are the indices of a matrix entry in the 2-dimensional representation.

For n = 4

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

To rotate this 90 degrees clockwise, we get

```
12 8 4 0
13 9 5 1
14 10 6 2
15 11 7 3
```

The mapping is now `i = 12 + y - (n * x)`

Using O(n^2) space, we just map the original index to the rotated index and copy over the entry in the original position. Very simple.

But I would like to know is there a way to do this in-place for a 1-dimensional representation of a square matrix. I know there are good algorithms out there for 2-d representations... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Any rotation can be decomposed into two consecutive reflections across two different axis. In your case, reflection can be done by swapping elements of a matrix. So it can be done in-place.

So for instance for rotating 90 degrees, the first reflection can be done around the x-axis, swapping the first row with the last row and then swapping the second row with the third row, you get:

```
12 13 14 15
8 9 10 11
4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3
```

Now the second reflection is around the main diagonal, like the transpose of a matrix, swapping elements across diagonal in a symmetric way:

```
12 8 4 0
13 9 5 1
14 10 6 2
15 11 7 3
```

Both reflections can be done swapping individual elements iteratively, so they can be done in-place. It doesn't matfer if the matrix is 1D or 2D.

C++ example of in-place rotation (1D array representation of matrix):

```
const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLS = ROWS;
int A[ROWS*COLS];

int index(int row, int col) { return col + COLS * row; }
void swap(int i, int j) { int a = A[i]; A[i] = A[j]; A[j] = a; }

// x-axis reflection
for(int row_i = 0 ; row_i < ROWS / 2; ++row_i) {
    int row_j = ROWS - row_i - 1;
    for(int col_i = 0 ; col_i < COLS ; ++col_i)
        swap( index(row_i, col_i), index(row_j, col_i) );
}

// diagonal reflection
for(int row_i = 0 ; row_i < ROWS; ++row_i) {
    for(int col_i = row_i + 1 ; col_i < COLS ; ++col_i)
        swap( index(row_i, col_i), index(col_i, row_i) );
}
```

Comment: i guess more specifically, how can I compute the destination index from the source index in the 1-D representation of the matrix when reflecting? I could not come up with a suitable formula when I have this 1-D rep